# how to use the accelerometer class in a WPF application in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, com, visual-studio-2015

For some reason everything I've found online says that the Accelerometer class is only for winRT applications and I can't use it unless I code against winRT. I dont understand what winRT is. And my app can't be a metro style app because I need special access to different APIs that I've read can only be accessed in a WPF app. Also windows 8 metro style apps wont work with windows 7 which I would like my app to work for. Also I've only recently started programming so explain it to me like I'm a 4 year old.

Thanks!

Comment: It's only for WinRT because moving a mid-tower atx case or full-tower atx case weighting about 20-30 pounds just to move a spaceship in a game would be a bit unwieldy. Might be easier on a laptop but could be dangerous for the HDD if it's not SSD.

Answer (score 2):

The accelerometer you are referring to is a specific WinRT (Windows RunTime) class which is not available in .NET.

WinRT API was made for phones and tablets, but also integrated in Windows 8 / 8.1. It's basically the API for 'Metro' apps and therefore requires such an app. It will definitely not work for Windows 7, since WinRT is not available for this OS. I'm also somehow wondering, why you would need an accelerometer on Win7 (Notebook?), but that is a different topic.

I've once tried to get WinRT stuff working in C#.NET, and to my knowledge, this is not possible.

If you can provide us any additional information about your idea, maybe we can offer you an acceptable alternative.

Comment: I have a lenovo yoga 2 pro. I'm just trying to make an alarm that will switch off when you take your surface/ultrabook and walk a certain distance. Just for educational reasons really. But is it true that if I use winRT instead of .NET I wont have access to different APIs and classes that need administrative access? If not will I lose ANY classes that I could potentially use in WPF when I decide to write the app in winRT?